# Taking information from a method ALAssetsLibrary

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks, alassetslibrary

I have this code, who get the asset url from my image:

```
NSUrl *caminhoImagem;

ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    // Request to save the image to camera roll
    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[imagem CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[imagem imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Erro na criacao de imagem");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Caminho da Imagem -> %@", assetURL);
            caminhoImagem = assetURL;

        }
    }];

    NSLog(@"%@",caminhoImagem);
```

What is happening is that the  **NSLog(@"%@",caminhoImagem);** returns me **('null')**, unless it is inserted within that method (more specifically within that Else), what I can not understand is that I made a reference using this command:

```
caminhoImagem = AssetUrl;
```

And it seems that is not saved the information, I suspect from the **'completionBlock'** which in my opinion seems to be blocking something, how can I fix this, and take the information that method?

Comment: And it is saving the image correct? imagem isn't null?

Comment: Yes image ins't null, I can confirm this with the code: NSLog(@"Caminho da Imagem -> %@", assetURL);, he returns me the correct asset!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block is executed asynchronously, so you need to call some method from inside the block to use the asset URL. You log which prints `null` is run before the block completes so it doesn't have access to the asset URL at that time.

Comment: So...I have to create a setter method inside the block and outside the block I can pick the information with method getter yes? does have another way to do this? change some commands in the method?

Comment: You can't make the method synchronous, you should be happy that it is asynchronous and doesn't block the main thread. You don't need an accessor method, you can use it direct in the block, but it's usually cleaner to call a method inside the block and pass the asset URL as a parameter.

Comment: Oh thanks, but I`m new in the Objective-C world, and I`ll be happy if you give me a link explaining asynchronous and synchronous  in objetive-c :)

Comment: There isn't really anything Obj-C specific here, synchronous and asynchronous are standard threading terms / semantics. What is it that you aren't clear on? https://www.google.com/search?q=multithreading+asynchronous